# Storybook and support for type modifiers on Import Names

Tags: javascript, typescript, storybook

My storybook seems to crash on launch since implementing [type
Modifiers on Import Names](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#type-modifiers-on-import-names) in my codebase a while back. When running storybook, it throws this type of error on multiple files:

```
SyntaxError: /[redacted]TextInput.tsx: Unexpected token, expected "," (7:7)

   5 |   forwardRef,
   6 |   useMemo,
>  7 |   type FocusEventHandler,
     |        ^
   8 | } from 'react';
   9 | import classNames from 'classnames';
  10 | import AutoResize from 'react-textarea-autosize';
    at Object._raise (/Users/[redacted/]node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack4/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:510:17)
```

Needless to say, these components do work in my regular [Webpacker](https://github.com/rails/webpacker) project.

I've tried upgrading storybook to the latest version and the v7 beta, but this doesn't make a difference.

It almost looks like storybook isn't using a recent version of Typescript. This syntax [was introduced in November 2021](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-5/#type-on-import-names)  in version 4.5 and we're now at 4.9. This seems silly for a well-maintained library, so I doubt that this is actually the case, but that leaves me rather confused.

Is there something I can do to make storybook accept this syntax?

Comment: This is something you should open as an Issue in the storybook repo, there isn't a question to answer. Yes, storybook is/was using an outdated version of typescript which does not support this.